# How can I execute a single nested ScalaTest Suite?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

In ScalaTest, it is possible to nest Suites by overriding the `nestedSuites` method. This is useful when an expensive to initialize resource, such as a container from the testcontainers library, is needed in several different suites that are otherwise unrelated. One can then initialize the resource in the outer Suite's `beforeAll` method, pass it to the nested Suites as a constructor parameter, and clean it up in the `afterAll` method.

However there's a downside: it's not possible any more to launch the inner Suites with sbt's `testOnly` command. How can I run these inner Suites individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sbt's internals do contain provisions for this in the form of the [NestedSuiteSelector](https://github.com/sbt/test-interface/blob/master/src/main/java/sbt/testing/NestedSuiteSelector.java) class, this is not exposed through the `testOnly` command. The only solution for now is therefore to run the ScalaTest Runner and pass appropriate command line arguments:
`test:runMain org.scalatest.tools.Runner -s my.project.OuterSuite -i my.project.InnerSuite -o`

More details can be found in the documentation: http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/tools/Runner$.html